# Asp.net(c#) paging without any control

Tags: c#, asp.net, paging

I am new and a novice to asp.net(C#).
I know little about binding to GridView Control.
But now I face some huge problems.
Some of my data are repeated and I control them with code-behind. Put my code in variable, append to div, not in GridView.
I also want paging for this.

Can anybody help? Ask me if you guys need something more specific.
I am a beginner, so I don't know what code to provide.

Here's the overview:
Doctors have many appointed place
appointed places have several day
several days have several times-shift ...

```
public void BindList(int start, int pagesize)
{
    lblPageIndex.Text = page.ToString();
    roles = DoctorBLL.GetAllDoctor(page, recordPerPage);
    List<int> rIDs = ((from r in roles select r.doctorID).Distinct()).ToList();
    foreach(int rID in rIDs)
    {
        doctorList.InnerHtml += "<table width='100%' border=1 cellspacing=0 style='border-collapse:collapse;margin-top:10px;'><tr>";
        List<DoctorEntity> dlist = roles.Where(role => role.doctorID == rID).ToList();
        if (dlist.Count > 0)
        {
            doctorList.InnerHtml += "<td>";
            doctorList.InnerHtml += "<h2>" + dlist.First().title + "</h2>";
            doctorList.InnerHtml += "<h3>" + dlist.First().name + "</h3>";
            doctorList.InnerHtml += "</td>";
            doctorList.InnerHtml += "<td>";
            doctorList.InnerHtml += dlist.First().qualification;
            doctorList.InnerHtml += "</td>";
            doctorList.InnerHtml += "</tr>";
            doctorList.InnerHtml += "<tr>";
            doctorList.InnerHtml += "<td colspan='3'>";
        }
        List<int> dirIDS = ((from r in dlist select r.directoryID).Distinct()).ToList();

        foreach (int dirid in dirIDS)
        {
            doctorList.InnerHtml += "<ul style='width:200px;float:left;list-style:none;'>";
            List<DoctorEntity> dirlist = dlist.Where(dt => dt.directoryID == dirid).ToList();
            if (dirlist.Count > 0)
            {
                doctorList.InnerHtml += "   <li><h4>" + dlist.First().directoryName + "</h4></li>";
            }
            foreach (DoctorEntity dir in dirlist)
            {
                doctorList.InnerHtml += "<li>" + dir.dayStr + " ( " + dir.startTime + " : " + dir.endTime + " ) </li>";
            }

            doctorList.InnerHtml += "</ul>";
        }
        doctorList.InnerHtml += "</td>";
        doctorList.InnerHtml += "</tr>";
        doctorList.InnerHtml += "</table>";
    }
    foreach (DoctorEntity entity in roles)
    {
        recordCount = entity.recordCount;
        break;
    }
    int flag = recordCount % recordPerPage;
    if (flag != 0)
    {
        flag = (recordCount / recordPerPage) + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        flag = recordCount / recordPerPage;
    }

    lblTotalPage.Text = flag.ToString();
    lblTotal.Text = recordCount.ToString();

    doctorList.DataBind();
}
#endregion
```

Comment: It would be much simpler and straightforward if you just use a grid view, especially for paging

Comment: As per your comments below, show us the sql that you were not able to get to work (grouping etc) and we will fix the sql.

Comment: SELECT 
    d.id doctorid, 
    d.name dname,
    d.title dtitle, 
    d.qualification dqua,
    dt.id dtid, 
    dt.name dtname,
    tt.day_id, 
    tt.start_time, 
    tt.end_time,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY d.id DESC) AS [RowNumber]
   FROM doctor d
   INNER JOIN time_table tt 
   ON d.id = tt.doctor_id
   INNER JOIN directory dt 
   ON dt.id = tt.directory_id
   ORDER BY d.id DESC
   
END

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cursors](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/data/mfc_database/sqlserver/article.php/c7177) and `Request.QueryString` to achieve paging without using ontrols.

Example : If your page url is something like http://localhost/MyApp/DoctorsList.aspx
then when you want to see the next 10 records just change the url to http://localhost/MyApp/DoctorsList.aspx?page=2

in you code behind use `int pageNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["page"])` to get the requested page, then use a database cursor to fetch the particular records based on the `pageNumber` value and then rebuild the table with code provided in the question. In short what i am saying is that instead of getting all the list of doctors, get n number of doctors using a cursor, and then use the `Request.QueryString` to browse through the remaining list.

But as Hassan Mokdad said in his comment, it would be better if you try with the grid view

Comment: Actually, I have done paging passing query string in the URL with php. Oh, by the way, I use store procedure, DAL, BLL because I am working on project. I want to make it much more simpler. But problem in GridView is When I extract data from database using JOIN(I have to) I got probs. Like when I extract Doctor who have 2 appointed place, then that doctor appear twice in the view. And that appointed place has two days related to that doctor. Appointed place appear even more. And so on and so on.

Comment: My friend suggest to load different entity by separating Doctor and Time-Table(days). But it will reduce performance because it have to access to database more than twice. It will overload the connection. And use GROUP BY in store procedure. But this store procedure won't work, it throws errors. I can't do that. Sooooo ... these are the problems by using GridView. If you have more method to solve. I am glad.

Thank you.

Comment: So what is the problem with doing paging using querystring in asp.net ?, and based on your comments, i guess the problem is with the query you were talking about, can you update the question with the query and some sample data, so that it would be easy to solve the problem